# reading single quotes from text file in java using BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, file-io, bufferedreader

I am using BufferedReader to read some string from text file but it won't read special characters like songle quotes " ' "... here us a code snip

```
 PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("input.txt");

     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Input.txt"));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
.
.
.
//some code
}
```

if the line had a single quote something like this: 'A'
and then I print the line..it outputs : â€™Aâ€™

Comment: sounds like an encoding issue? what encoding is your file? or Java program?

Answer (score 4):

BufferedReader can read any text with a standard encoding.  A problem arises when the encoding used by the file doesn't match the default encoding you use to read the file.  This is not something which can be determined automagically, you need to know what the correct encoding is to read it reliably.

```
String filename = ...
Charset encoding = ...
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                             new InputStreamReader(
                                 new FileInputStream(filename), encoding))) {
    // read the br
}
```

Comment: The standard encoding as determined by the platform running the code, yes?

Comment: Java determines a standard encoding for your platform based on environment variables.  Sometimes it gets it wrong, but more often you have a file which used a non-default encoding like UTF-8 or Windows-1252-1, or ISO-8859-1

Comment: In this case, the appropriate Charset would be `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.  â€™ is the result of reading the UTF-8 byte sequence for `'\u2019'` (apostrophe) with a FileReader that is using windows-1252 or a similiar Windows charset.

Comment: @VGR +1 I won't ask you how you know that ;)